# How to Find Positional embeddings from BARTTokenizer?

Tags: pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers, summarization, bart

The objective is to add token embeddings (customized- obtained using different model) and the positional Embeddings.

Is there a Way I can find out positonal embedding along with the token embeddings for an article(length 500-1000 words) using BART model.

```
tokenized_sequence = tokenizer(sentence, padding='max_length', truncation=True, max_length=512, return_tensors="pt")
```

the output is `input_ids` and `attention_mask` but not parameter to return `position_ids` like in BERT model.

```
bert.embeddings.position_embeddings('YOUR_POSITIONS_IDS')
```

Or the only way to obtain Positional Embedding is using sinusoidal positional encoding?

Comment: Can you clarify your sentence between the two code blocks. I assume "linke" should mean "like" and not "linked".

Comment: Yes, It is "Like"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tokenizer is not responsible for the embeddings. It only generates the ids to be fed into the embedding layer.
Barts embeddings are learned, i.e. the embedding come from their own embedding layer.

You can retrieve both types of embeddings like this. Here `bart` is a `BartModel`. The encoding is (roughly) done like this:

```py
embed_pos = bart.encoder.embed_positions(input_ids)
inputs_embeds = bart.encoder.embed_tokens(input_ids)
hidden_states = inputs_embeds + embed_pos
```

Full working code:

```py
from transformers import BartForConditionalGeneration, BartTokenizer

bart = BartForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("facebook/bart-base", forced_bos_token_id=0)
tok = BartTokenizer.from_pretrained("facebook/bart-base")
example_english_phrase = "UN Chief Says There Is No <mask> in Syria"
input_ids = tok(example_english_phrase, return_tensors="pt").input_ids

embed_pos = bart.model.encoder.embed_positions(input_ids) * bart.model.encoder.embed_scale # by default the scale is 1.0
inputs_embeds = bart.model.encoder.embed_tokens(input_ids)
hidden_states = inputs_embeds + embed_pos
```

---

Note that `embed_pos` is invariant to the actual token ids. Only their position matters. "New" embeddings are added if the input grows larger without changing the embeddings of the earlier positions:

These cases yield the same embeddings:
`embed_positions([0, 1]) == embed_positions([123, 241]) == embed_positions([444, 3453, 9344, 3453])[:2]`

Comment: Can you please explain last line. ```
embed_positions([0, 1]) == embed_positions([123, 241]) == embed_positions([444, 3453, 9344, 3453])[:2]```

Comment: The last line is meant to indicate that these three cases are the same. Edited the post to make it clearer.

Comment: And what is best to generate embeddings, Pass entire article as string or list of sentences to tokenizer method?

Comment: For an article I would try to do everything, as everything is related, definitely not sentence for sentence. Problems arise if your text is too long, then a sliding window is a solution (e.g. 512 tokens, stride 256). You should check how many tokens your article generates and the limit of your model. 1000 words could be > 2048 tokens > `max_length=512`, this does **silently truncate**. Yet, you could still calculate the embeddings for longer inputs and manually combine them with the code given above. BART should have a limit there how long it can go (maybe 2048 tokens).

Comment: I recommend to create a new question focusing on that problem with enough code for reproduction.

Comment: Embedding generated by the above code and the BART model (output = model(input_ids.input_ids)) is different. That's why getting hallucinations.